# How to preselect a dropdown selection for a form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, dropdown, choice-field

I have a form that is specific for from a category in a dropdown select.
When the user fills it out I would like the dropdown form to be pre-selected and greyed out or hidden so that the filed value is saved when submitted.

For example the form is for "fruits".

Name of r fruit - open text field
What state it's from - open text field
Dropdown with several choices - preselected to "fruits" from the other choices "vegetables" and "dry goods"

Answer (score 0):

You can add script editor on the form and add below script into it.

Below script should run once SP.js is loaded.

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('fieldName').SetValue('FormName')
eg: SPUtility.GetSPField('DropDown').SetValue('Fruit')
```

Comment: Hello Ankitkumar , I am sorry I am not much of a coder - what other code do I need to add before it please? Thank you.

Comment: Can't seem to get this working - Arrgh so need to get this done :(